# Wrong path for images in Partial View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use images inside a Partial View like this:

```
<img src="~Content/Images/Layout/bild.jpg" />
```

This isn't working! When I view the code I can see that the path is changed to this:

```
<img src="/Views/Shared/~Content/Images/Layout/bild.jpg" />
```

Why this and how should I do get the right path for the images?

Comment: Consider changing `~Content/Images/Layout/bild.jpg` to `~/Content/Images/Layout/bild.jpg`. Note the upfront backslash

Comment: @BobKaufman Great! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Always add the ~ (root) then (/) and the other path :

```
<img src="~/Content/Images/Layout/bild.jpg" />
```

and it's will work